# Getting QGIS interface in French on Mac

Tags: qgis-3, internationalization, interface, french

I have just downloaded QGIS 3.4.15-Madeira on my Mac (Mojave 10.14.6) which local settings include French. 
The interface language is however American English.

I went to settings and unticked "override system locale" and restarted QGIS, but it does not solve the issue. English remain the default interface language.

Answer (score 4):

The following instruction is in French so that a non-English-speaking user can set QGIS to French.

> Pour avoir QGIS en français, tu dois avoir les paramètres suivants
>   dans l'onglet `Préférences`. Redémarrage QGIS une fois que tu as
>   effectué les changements.

In order to get QGIS in french, you must have the following parameters in the `Settings`. Restart QGIS once the changes have been made.

[image]